# App Engine traffic splitting is not persisting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When splitting traffic by cookies, we're observing the following behavior:
GOOGAPPUID cookie does not receive a number between 0-999, but rather a string which resembles this form: xCgsIARD8AiDF1PjnBQ
Even though the client has the cookie he is not always sent to the same version, every few minutes the version the client is directed to is switched.

How do we remedy this?

Comment: The string you are seeing is actually a serialised value from a [proto buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) that isn't intended to be read as a number by the user.  Can you confirm if the cookie remains the same each time the version the client is sent to changes? What expiration is set for the cookie?

Comment: @CorinneWhite the expiry for the cookie is set to ~2 years in the future. Regarding the cookie behavior, in the phase of 20 mins we observed two versions serving with same cookie, and the cookie changed as well.

Comment: I can see you've opened a case to investigate this with Cloud Support. Would you be able to post an answer here when you come to a resolution so people with the same problem might be able to benefit?

Comment: @CorinneWhite will do

Comment: @CorinneWhite sad to find out that it is a 3 years old bug, which is yet to be fixed by the App Engine team: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35899666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently it's a bug from 2015 ([Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35899666)) that has not been fixed yet.

**We've implemented a partial solution though:**

If you have versions A and B, split 30%/70% then if you set the GOOGAPPUID cookie manually to values between 0-299 you'll get to version A, or to values between 300-999 you'll get to version B, consistently, across requests.

Knowing that, on the relevant handlers of our app (you might need to do it for all handlers of your app), we check if the incoming request already has a GOOGAPPUID cookie AND that it's a number. If it is a number, we leave it as is.

If it's not present or not a number it means that we have not set it before. So we check on which version we are (because the App Engine traffic splitting works well, it's only the persistence cookie mechanism is broken), and if we're on version A, we set the cookie to a value between 0-299, if we're on version B we set the cookie to value of 300-999.

This patch will fill the gap of Google's issue with GOOGAPPUID cookies and will give your user a persistent experience across requests.

Comment: I have tested, does it not work for this way